# Neo4j: No Change/No record vs Null Result

Tags: neo4j

Why does deleted node property return "null" sometimes and sometimes returns error "Node with id ## has been deleted in this transaction"? This is driving me totally bananas as I cannot find any rhyme or reason for it.

```
CREATE (node:Node)
DELETE node
RETURN node.Property
```

Returns null

```
CREATE (node:Node)
DELETE node
RETURN node.property
```

Returns Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound: Node with id ## has been deleted in this transaction

```
CREATE (node:Node)
DELETE node
RETURN node.exists
```

Returns Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound: Node with id ## has been deleted in this transaction

```
CREATE (node:Node)
DELETE node
RETURN node.banana
```

Returns null

```
CREATE (node:Node)
DELETE node
RETURN node.Banana
```

Returns null

```
CREATE (node:Node)
DELETE node
RETURN node {.*}
```

returns {}

```
CREATE (node:Node)
DELETE node
RETURN node {.exists, .banana, .Banana, .property, .Property}
```

Returns Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound: Node with id ## has been deleted in this transaction

```
CREATE (node:Node)
SET node.Banana="exists"
DELETE node
RETURN node.Banana
```

Returns Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound: Node with id ## has been deleted in this transaction

Anybody understand this behavior, which makes no sense to me? It looks like if I return a property that was set in the system at some point then I get the error, else I get null.

What's the best way to handle a node that has been deleted if you want to return null and not an error?

TIA!

Comment: These return null for me. Maybe some version specific behavior?

Comment: Ah- thanks for checking. This is even weirder! I'm using an older version of Enterprise. Perhaps it's a fixed bug.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across the same bug, I am using this workaround:
CREATE (node:Node)
SET node.id="thatone"
DELETE node

WITH 0 as forgetnode

MATCH (n:Node {id:"thatone"})
RETURN n.id